# Active Directory Authentication when server is not Member of Domain

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

I've following situation we have a server which is not memebr of a domain. On this server there is an asp.net application with forms authenticaton enabled. Is it possible to change to active directory provider without putting the server into a domain?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the site to use basic authentication you can tell it what domain to use for authentication.